# Magento import - Skip row sku is not defined

Tags: php, csv, magento, import

I'm trying to import a csv file to Magento, but it always give me an error saying that the sku field is not defined, but it is.

I tried changing the encoding to UTF-8 and ANSI, still didnt work.

I've mapped this native fields from the database, excluding custom attributes:         "store","websites","visibility","is_in_stock","name","qty","price","sku","description","short_description","type","attribute_set" and "weight".

Am I missing some mandatory field?

I also have two columns (custom attributes) which are empty. Could this be the cause of the error? Please HELP ME! It's a list of +3000 products, and i cant add them one by one.

Thanks in advance, any question ask me.

UPDATE

is there any order for the csv fields? i've followed the order i've mapped in magento, and most of the native fields are in the end.

The error message when i try to check the data in System > Import/Export > Import is:
Can not find required columns: sku

Comment: Post the actual error message in your question please.

Comment: @Andre Ferraz the error is "Can not find required columns: sku"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of CSV file. I would suggest you to first export your product to a CSV you can do this via `System - Import/Export - Export`, select your entity type to product and export file format CSV, then click continue.

You should then see how your CSV file should look like. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using one excel column for each field, the exported result show all fields and values in the same column but different rows for each product. is that supposed to be the correct way? I mean am i going to need to change the structure of my csv

Comment: Yes it need to match the structure of the magento csv you exported

Answer (score 0):

I had a list of 3000 products and it wasn't possible to restructure the csv, it would take a lot of time.

So I didnt use any of your answers, instead, i filled all the empty rows with default data, and import it using MS Excel XML. Then problem was that the products didnt show up in the products list. I analysed the dataabse and found the records there, but the field status didnt have the correct value, 1. I updated that and it finally showed up.

Thanks anyways guys. :)